# Failed to verify bitcode in BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/BarcodeScannerFramework

Tags: nativescript

I am getting this error when I export adhoc build from XCode 10.2

Failed to verify bitcode in BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/BarcodeScannerFramework:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/fj/0lbn1q2s38943yr8x40lsycc0000gn/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.~~~SI1oYn/Payload/eslnativescript.app/Frameworks/BarcodeScannerFramework.framework/BarcodeScannerFramework (armv7)

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to bitcode. It appeared when the framework contained simulator slices (i386 x86_64)

Adding a run script phase to build phases of the target with following code helped in getting rid of the error.

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and removes unused architectures.

find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Credits: http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/